# Tikz Hiding a line behind a title

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to hide the line behind my rectangle, but I am not having luck. I tried a fill command and also moved the code around, but the line keeps going through the rectangle.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}


\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 left=.635cm,
        right=.635cm,
        top=2.54cm,
        bottom=2.54cm
 }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}




\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,12)--(9,12)node[midway,sloped, draw, rounded rectangle]{\Large{Lessons Title}};
\draw (0,24)--(9,24) node[midway, sloped, draw, rounded rectangle, fill=white!50] {\Huge{Exit Slip}};
\draw[dashed] (9,24)--(9,12);

\draw (0,12 )-- (0,24) -- (18,24) -- (18,12) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

'''
```

Comment: `fill =white` in the nodes options and change the drawing order (draw the two nodes last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the comment that gave you the most simple solution possible, here is something you could do, to make your code a little more efficient:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,calc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=0.25in,vmargin=1in}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style={draw,rounded rectangle,fill=white}]   
        \node[rectangle,minimum width=18cm,minimum height=12cm,draw] (A) {};
        \draw[dashed] (A.south) -- (A.north);
        
        \node[label,font=\Large] at ($(A.south)!.5!(A.south west)$){Lessons Title};
        \node[label,font=\Huge] at ($(A.north)!.5!(A.north west)$) {Exit Slip};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note also that: `tikz` loads `xcolor` and `graphicx` so you do not need to load them again (you can if you want to, of course). `pgfplots` is currently `1.18` and you were originally loading several `tikz` libraries multiple times, which doesn't hurt, but also doesn't add anything productive to your code.

Comment: Thank you Markus!